# How do you say "to have sex" in a formal way

Tags: phrases, expressions, synonyms

How would you say "to have sex" in a more formal way?

Also, is it *to intercourse* or *to have intercourse*?

Comment: formal in what context?  A medical journal, a police report? A newspaper?

Comment: Funny question coming from the Beast. Coitus. Merriam Webster: 
 
 
Definition of coitus
:  physical union of male and female genitalia accompanied by rhythmic movements :  sexual intercourse

Comment: By formal I mean something you'd write in a report for example. Let's say you're writing a history paper and you need to say 2 kings had sex (it is just an example). A newspaper should be the same. Also, I'm just looking for verbs (not nouns).

Comment: I think the answer may depend on ***why*** the intercourse needs to be mentioned in the report.  Sometimes it only needs to be implied by mentioning the result.

Comment: In history, they would say King X took a mistress.

Comment: A newspaper report is not the same as say a report in a historical journal article. A highly researched academic article, with a biological interest might say "The couple copulated several times over the week-long period", the New Yorker magazine might say "The pair went at it like rabbits over the week-long period", but USA Today would say "The couple had a honeymoon-like vacation for a week". That is, even more oblique than the Bible, where people are 'knowing' each other left and right.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both *to have sex* and *to have intercourse* are fairly formal (as opposed to slang such as *[shag](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/shag#shag_Verb_500)*, *[make out](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/make_out)*, or *[screw](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/screw)*.)

If you really need something more formal/euphemistic, you could go with ***copulate***:

> ***[Copulate](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/copulate)***
>
> VERB
>
> [NO OBJECT]
>
> Have sexual intercourse.
>     *‘only the dominant male copulates with the female’*
>     *‘after about twenty minutes, they copulate again’*

Or perhaps ***fornicate***:

> ***[Fornicate](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/fornicate)***
>
> VERB
>
> [NO OBJECT]
>
> *formal, humorous*
>   Have sexual intercourse with someone one is not married to.

I think that ***copulate*** is probably your best option if *have sex* and *have intercourse* won't do.

Comment: I think you misunderstand the idea of euphemism.  "Copulate" is not one.  "Make the beast with two backs" is.

Comment: make out does not mean to have sexual intercourse.

Comment: Frankly, copulate and fornicate sound legal and/or Victorian.

Comment: 1. you have to say "to have intercourse"? Is "to intercourse" incorrect? 2. Is to have intercourse more formal than to have sex? 3. Something like this would be correct?: "he was wishing to copulate with her on her  upcoming birthday"

Comment: @cobaltduck -- No, I get euphemism.  In our (US -- we're wackos) culture,  _copulate_ and _fornicate_ and _engage in coitus_ (as Sheldon Cooper would say) are euphemism for the more common/blunt _have sex_.   [A mild or indirect word or expression substituted for one considered to be too harsh or blunt when referring to something unpleasant or embarrassing.](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/euphemism)  Yes, we're very screwed up, here in the US.

Comment: _Make out_ doesn't necessarily mean intercourse is included, but it often does.  At least where I'm from.

Comment: @TheBeast -- Yes, you have to **have** intercourse, you can't just intercourse.  I would say (and, again, this is based on the US) that _to have intercourse_ is more formal than _to have sex_ at least in common usage.  I would say _he **wished** to copulate..._ but yes.

Comment: Nice, those were my main questions.

Comment: @TheBeast - I doubt anyone would really ever say, “he was wishing to copulate with her on her upcoming birthday.”  grammatical- yes, idiomatic? Not by a long shot.

Answer (score 4):

There is also the term

> **Coitus**
> ˈkōədəs,ˈkoidəs/
> noun
>
> sexual intercourse

*The two people engaged in coitus.*

Comment: [Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=coidus&oq=coidus&aqs=chrome..69i57.1470j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#q=coitus+definition)

Comment: Bizarre! Thanks. So it seems the first represents the trisyllabic pronunciation, and the second the bisyllabic pronunciation

Comment: Take out the "were."

Answer (score 2):

As a biologist (and traditionalist) I personally dislike the expression “have sex” as a euphemism for the linguistically venerable and specific “fuck”, because ‘sex’ is a term used to differentiates males and females. “Have sex”  seems to be a modern contraction of:

> **have sexual intercourse**

This should be formal enough for anyone, as the term is used in British law courts, [e.g.](https://www.leeds.ac.uk/law/hamlyn/rvr.htm)

> 1991 July 1; Oct. 23
>   Lord Keith of Kinkel, Lord Brandon of Oakbrook, Lord Griffiths, Lord
>   Ackner and Lord Lowry
>
> Crime - Sexual offences - Rape - Husband and wife living apart -
>   Husband attempting *sexual intercourse* with wife against her will -
>   Whether husband immune from charge of attempted rape - Sexual Offences
>   (Amendment) Act 1976 (c. 82), s. 1(1)

Comment: "To have sexual relations" covers just about everything and isn't a "wet" word.

Comment: @Xanne — Why did you post this as a comment to my answer? I did not employ either the term “sexual relations”, or the slang and imprecise word “wet”. (I have no idea what you mean by it.) The term “sexual intercourse” is different and used in a precise legal sense, as my quotation from an appeal for a rape conviction illustrates.

Comment: It seems an option in comparison to "to have sexual intercourse" with fit more with formality.  I didn't mean to criticize your answer.  I'll upvote it.